# save canvas image via PHP base64

Tags: php, image, canvas, base64

I am saving an image in php via AJAX from canvas.
But the image is not saved. And I get a blank black image saved.

AJAX Js code:

```
$("#imgdrawing").drawImage({
  source: $("#Aj_iMG").attr("src"),
  x: 150, y: 150,
  width:640,
  height:480,
  fromCenter:false
});
var dataURL = $('#imgdrawing').getCanvasImage('png');
console.log(dataURL);
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo($base_url); ?>ipl/save/",
      data: { 
         imgBase64: dataURL,
         appname:"ipl"
           }
        }).done(function(o) {
      console.log('saved'); 
    });
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$img1 = trim($_POST['imgBase64']);
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = 'photo.png';
file_put_contents($fileName,$fileData);
?>
```

I tried creating with both images $img and $img1 .
Both give me same black image. $img is the image I tried uploading by converting it with third party png to base64 converter.

```
$img = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```